# I created rails app with -j esbuild --css bootstrap flag but the bootstrap is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

I have a rails app that I created using `rails new BudgetApp -j esbuild --css bootstrap`. When I created my first controller and view and navigated to their route I got the an error saying

> The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.

[image]

After some searching, I tried to replace the following line at app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

By

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/application.js", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

but this time I get the page with no bootstrap effect and with an error message like saying

> Can't find stylesheet to import

[image]

I also uncommented

```
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

in the gem file and ran

```
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

but not sure if it was relevant

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to start the server while ensuring the assets get compiled into the build directory.

```
bin/dev
```

This will start the server as well as watch for JS and CSS changes

Comment: I tried `bin/dev` command on powershell it is not working then I tried it on bash this time it gives me ' 'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,' error